# referencing another for loop

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml

```
<batch>
    <items>
         <item>...</item>
         <item>...</item>
         <item>...</item>
         <item>
              <place>...</place>
              <stuff>...</stuff>
         </item>
    <items>
    <tasks>
        <task>
             <place>...</place>
             <time>...</time>
        <task>...</task>
        <task>...</task>
        <task>...</task>
    </tasks>
<batch>
```

I was wanted each time written down and the time of the task if the task and item were at the same place.  I was going to use

```
<xsl:for-each select="//batch/items/item">
      <xsl:value-of select="stuff"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="//batch/tasks/task">
             <xsl:iftest="item/place=task/place">task/time</xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

However the referencing of item/place is wrong.  How do I fix this?  Is this even possible?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide an input XML with a few actual examples, and the desired output XML (or text or HTML)? It is hard to figure out your exact goal from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the task/s whose place matches the current item's place, start by defining a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** as:

```
<xsl:key name="task-by-place" match="task" use="place" />
```

and then use it as (for example):

```
<xsl:template match="/batch">
    <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="stuff"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('task-by-place', place)/time"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```